# Grid column fr doesn't apply

Tags: css, css-grid

I encountered a problem with my grid code. I would like to display two fields to each other. I created two 1fr 1fr and each field should take one fr. I tried even grid areas and somehow it doesn´t function, but still fields won´t align to grid. 
Thank you very much. I'm thankful for any ideas you might have

```
//=========================================================================
// [1]Contact Form
.contact {
  @include flexy (
    $width:100%,
    $dir: column,
  );
  grid-area: form; 
  display: grid; 
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas: 
  "form-heading form-heading"
  "grid-form grid-form";
}
// Heading and Paragraph Text
.form-text {
  @include flexy (
    $dir: column,
  );
  grid-area: form-heading;
}
// Whole Form
.form {
  @include flexy (
    $width: 100%,
    $just: center,
  );
  @include mg("md") {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 20px;
  };

  grid-area: grid-form;
}
// Each Field
.field {
  @include flexy (
    $dir: column,
    $width: 100%,
  );
  padding: 5% 0 5% 0;
}
// ID for Grid
#grid-name {
  grid-column: 1/2;
}
#grid-email {
  grid-column: 2/3 ;
}
#grid-condition {

  grid-column: 1/2;
}
#grid-price {

  grid-column: 2/3;
}
#grid-company {

}
#grid-lease {

}
#grid-other {

}
#grid-message {

}
#grid-submit-btn {

}

 <div class="contact">
          <div class="form-text">
            <h2>Get in touch</h2>
            <p>Phasellus convallis elit id ullamcorper pulvinar. Duis aliquam turpis mauris, eu ultricies erat malesuada quis. Aliquam dapibus, lacus eget hendrerit bibendum, urna est aliquam sem, sit amet imperdiet est velit quis lorem.</p>
         </div>
          <div class="form">
            <form method="post" action="#">
                  <div class="field half" id="grid-name">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"/>
                  </div>
                  <div class="field half" id="grid-email">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="field half" id="grid-condition">
                   <label for="condition">Condition</label>
                   <input type="text" name="text" id="condition" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="field half" id="grid-price">
                    <label for="price">Price</label>
                    <input type="text" name="price" id="price" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="field half" id="grid-company">
                    <label for="company">Company</label>
                    <input type="text" name="company" id="company" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="field half" id="grid-lease">
                   <label for="lease">Lease</label>
                   <input type="text" name="lease" id="lease" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="field half" id="grid-other">
                    <label for="other">Other</label>
                    <input type="text" name="other" id="other" />
                  </div>
                  <div class="field" id="grid-message">
                    <label for="message">Message</label>
                    <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="5"></textarea>
                  </div>             
                <ul class="actions">
                 <li><button class="btn-form" type="submit" id="submit-btn"> Send Message</button></li>
                </ul>
            </form>  
          </div>        
       </div>
```

Comment: you defined 1fr on column and you made each area to take both of them on each row

Comment: What do you propose?

Comment: I have problem with aligning inputs in the form

Answer (score 0):

I had to implement grid not on .form class, but form itself.